# How to make horizontal image grid gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have thumbnail image and its name, size and delete button beneath it and same sort of orientation to the next thumbnail image appearing beside it. It must look like horizontal image gallery. Now it's showing vertical image gallery.Please help.
Concerned Lines of code looks like

```
 for(var i = 0; i < o["files"].length; i++)
                {


                     str += '  <tr> \
                        <tr> <td>                       \
                         <span class="preview">\
                         <a class="fancyOpen" rel="fancyOpen" href="'+o["files"][i].url+'"><img src="'+o["files"][i].thumbnail_url+'" /></a>       \
                         </span>                 \
                         </td>  </tr>                                       \
                        <tr>   <td>  \
                        <p class="name">'+o["files"][i].name+'</p>\
                        </td></tr>\
                         <tr></td>
                        '+o["files"][i].size+ ' KB';<td></tr>

                        if(showDel === undefined)
                        {
                        str += '<tr><td>\
                        <form method="get" >       \
                        <input type="hidden" autocomplete="false" name="iid" value="'+o["files"][i].id+'" >    \
                        \
                        <a  href="'+o["files"][i].delete_url+'&iid='+o["files"][i].id+'" target="frametoDelete" class="btn btn-danger delete">  \
                        <span>Delete</span>   \
                        </a>\
                        </form></td></tr>';


                        }

                        else

                        {}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
       var str='<table border=1><tr>';
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
          {
        str += '<td height=150px valign=bottom>  <div height=100px class="preview">Thumbnail</div><table border=1><tr><td>   <span class="name">'+"NAME"+'</span>   </td><td>'+"SIZE"+ 'KB+ </td></tr><tr><td colspan=2 align=center>DELETE</td></table> </td>';

                           
          }
        str+='</tr></table>';
        document.write(str);
```